# How to use php to sort select box list in gravity forms?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, gravity-forms-plugin, array-multisort

I have completed most of the translation set-up on my WordPress site, but one outstanding issue is that when users switch to, say, Spanish, the list of countries in a dropdown box on my sign-up page is still in English.

I have an array, $countries, which maps the English to Spanish country names, and have successfully replaced the English with the Spanish names using the following which is part of a loop through the form fields:

```
$options = $field["choices"];
foreach ( $options as $cy_key => $option ) {
    $country_en = $option[text];
    $country_es = $countries[$country_en];
    $form["fields"][$key]["choices"][$cy_key][text] = $country_es;
}
```

If you are unfamiliar with Gravity Forms but know PHP, I now have a nested array like this:

```
$form["fields"][$key]["choices"] = array (
    array (
        text=>"Belgica",
        value=>"Belgium",
        isSelected=>'',
        price=>''),
    array (
        text=>"Francia",
        value=>"France",
        isSelected=>'',
        price=>''),
    array (
        text=>"España",
        value=>"Spain",
        isSelected=>'',
        price=>'')
    );
```

I want to sort this array based on the nested array text values (i.e. "Belgica", "Francia", "España").

I've looked through the php.net documentation and I suspect the solution may require array_multisort but I can't find a comparable example, or understand them if they are.

Comment: why you are not using the built in get_text translation functions ?? like `__("France","my_text_domain")` ...

Comment: They are not available. Gravity Forms generates the select list for the dropdown box and retrieves those values from a db table. You can intercept the country names and change them via get_text before they are displayed on the admin pages, but once you have added them to the form and they are stored in the db there is no simple to change them. The only solution I know is to use one of the hooks available before the form renders to swap out the values. I framed my question in terms of the gravity forms example, but it is really just a PHP sort question.

Comment: but you do know you can also translate __($variable,"my_text_domain") , right ? at least I have before .. that means you can translate also things that are pulled from a DB ( or any string for that matter .. )

Comment: I'm familiar with using variables for things you _don't_ want translating, e.g. "You are viewing comment %x of %y". I've read a lot about get_text and haven't come across people using variables how you're suggesting, so I'd be interested to know more, **but**, the select list is generated by the GF plug-in and isn't wrapped in get_text calls anyway...

Comment: It will be difficult to demonstrate it all here in a comment ( not to mention completely off topic ) you might want to open a new question for it - or just try it yourself . as for the list being generated by the plugin - it is irrelevant - because you need to use the translation function on the variable you are passing to the plugin BEFORE it generates the list . I have used this same technique in the past for generating dropdown lists ( in different context )